# Select second instance of record ID in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to find when each customer placed their second order and I can't think of how to do it!

Basic table structure:

```
Order ID    Customer ID    Order Date
1           123            2014-09-12
2           456            2014-10-22
3           456            2014-11-01   <-- THIS IS CUST 456's 2ND ORDER
4           789            2014-11-01
5           123            2014-11-09   <-- THIS IS CUST 123's 2ND ORDER
6           225            2014-11-11
```

How do I get the second orders out of the table using mysql?

The real table has over 200K of orders and over 70K customers, each ranging from only having placed one order to having placed 20+ orders since 2010.

Comment: is there a column which counts how many orders they customer has placed?

Comment: Is `Order ID` always increasing? If so, that could be the sort clause.

Comment: @Harry - there's no column in the table that counts how many orders but can be made within the query using count()

Comment: @Jack - yes, Order ID is always increasing, it's an auto increment field (primary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the 2nd order date then a self join to exclude the first order, and a MIN to get the remaining earliest order:-

```
SELECT t1.CustomerId, MIN(t2.OrderDate)
FROM 
(   SELECT CustomerId, MIN(OrderDate) AS OrderDate
    FROM some_table  
    GROUP BY CustomerId
) t1
INNER JOIN some_table t2
ON t1.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
AND t1.OrderDate < t2.OrderDate
GROUP BY t1.CustomerId
```

If you need other details (such as the order id) then you would need to use this as a sub query and join it back against the main table.

EDIT - Might be possible to simplify this as follows:-

```
SELECT t1.CustomerId, MIN(t2.OrderDate)
FROM some_table t1
INNER JOIN some_table t2
ON t1.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
AND t1.OrderDate < t2.OrderDate
GROUP BY t1.CustomerId
```

This is joining the table against itself based on the customer id, but also that the order date is larger on the 2nd join of the table.

This is likely to generate a massive amount of data while doing the calculation.

I have a feeling I have missed something with this though.

Comment: i'm going to give this a try :)

Comment: Marking this answer as correct as it looks like it works the way I want it to, thank you very much!